# RaspberryPi Python TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'float'

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, sensors, temperature, raspberry-pi-zero

I've recently been building some Raspberry pi temperature sensors, using Pi zeros, to monitor temperature spikes on some computer floors.
I'm using the initial state set up and sending the data to their dashboard.
Well I got one perfectly set up with no issues, and its sending the data fine. But when I go to set up the second, the exact same way, with the exact same code I keep getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "tempsensor.py", line 20, in <module>

 temp_f = format(temp_c * 9.0 / 5.0 + 32.0, ".2f")

 TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'float'
```

I'm not fluent in python, but I've tried looking up similar issues, but nothing that could really help me with mine.
But what I dont understand is this code is basically a copy paste of the other, as well as what other people use.
Why would this be coming back with an error when nothing has changed?

also listed below is the full code that i've been using.
Thanks for any help!

```
import Adafruit_DHT
from ISStreamer.Streamer import Streamer
import time

# --------- User Settings ---------
SENSOR_LOCATION_NAME = "Office"
BUCKET_NAME = ":partly_sunny: Room Temperatures"
BUCKET_KEY = "rt0129"
ACCESS_KEY = "PLACE YOUR INITIAL STATE ACCESS KEY HERE"
MINUTES_BETWEEN_READS = 10
METRIC_UNITS = False
# ---------------------------------

streamer = Streamer(bucket_name=BUCKET_NAME, bucket_key=BUCKET_KEY, access_key=ACCESS_KEY)
while True:
    humidity, temp_c = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(Adafruit_DHT.DHT22, 4)
    if METRIC_UNITS:
        streamer.log(SENSOR_LOCATION_NAME + " Temperature(C)", temp_c)
    else:
        temp_f = format(temp_c * 9.0 / 5.0 + 32.0, ".2f")
        streamer.log(SENSOR_LOCATION_NAME + " Temperature(F)", temp_f)
    humidity = format(humidity,".2f")
    streamer.log(SENSOR_LOCATION_NAME + " Humidity(%)", humidity)
    streamer.flush()
    time.sleep(60*MINUTES_BETWEEN_READS)
```

Comment: `Adafruit_DHT.read_retry` appears to be returning `None`. Double check the documentation for that method to see what that means.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `temp_c` variable is getting set to `None`. That's what the exception `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'float'` is telling you.

I don't know why that's happening, but given that it's happening in your call to `Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(Adafruit_DHT.DHT22, 4)` I would guess that either the call isn't being made correctly. Or more likely if the same code is running on another Pi, that the sensor isn't installed or set up properly.

Comment: Thanks for commenting! After you said " I would guess that either the call isn't being made correctly. Or more likely if the same code is running on another Pi, that the sensor isn't installed or set up properly." 
it made me think well maybe the sensor wasnt working properly and made me recheck the hardware. 
It ended up being a dead sensor! 
Swapped it out and its working now. But I would of never checked it had you not said maybe the pi/sensor isnt working.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`Adafruit_DHT.read_retry` is not correctly returning `temp_c`. Therefore it is `NoneType` and cannot be multiplied by a float.
I recommend you try to debug by calling the function with different parameters and `print` the returned values until you figure how to correctly call it according to the capabilities of your device.